# VideoJs: Play videos on a loop without gaps

Tags: jquery, html, video.js

How can I play multiple videos with VideoJs like one video? I want to remove the gaps between videos.

I want to play videos as on LifeMirror: http://www.lifemirror.org/

This is my code.. I'm using videojs-playlist plugin to make the playlist of videos

```
var player = videojs("video",
  {
      controls: false,
      width: 320,
      height: 240,
      children: {
          controlBar: {
              children: {
                  muteToggle: false,
                  volumeControl: false
              }
          }
      }
  });

  var videos = [
    {
      src : [
        'assets/videos/video3.mp4'
      ],
      poster : 'assets/images/image1.jpg',
      title : 'Video 1'
    },
    {
      src : [
        'assets/videos/video4.mp4',
        'assets/videos/video4.ogv'
      ],
      poster : 'assets/images/image2.jpg',
      title : 'Video 2'
    }
  ];

  player.playList(videos, {
    getVideoSource: function(vid, cb) {
      cb(vid.src, vid.poster);
    }
  });
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you paste some of your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On LifeMirror they have one visible and multiple hidden video elements (display: none). They are just changing currently visible video on current video 'ended' event. You can inspect video element in Google Developer Tools and check how it is working.

Probably this approach can be good for you. Just remember to preload all the videos before to remove gaps between videos.

Comment: Thanks man.. I just fixed the issue and I preloaded videos and than work with display it worked nice ;)